# Content flickering on Safari

Tags: css, canvas, webkit-perspective

I'm using webkit-perspective to animate slide transitions in css. It works well on all major browsers except safari. 

The second slide has a flicker on the text. I found solutions here that includes `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`
on the parent element. But it didn't work for me. 
The site is: http://www.venicedev.com 
 I think this is happening because of my canvas element on the back of the text. But I can't found any turnaround for this.
Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

adding z-index:1; seems to have helped

Comment: Yes, to `.content-block { ... }`.

Comment: I've updated the live version with the z-index on the content block, but I'm still having the flickering here.